# Why did this error occur in the photoelectric experiment?

Tags: error-analysis, photoelectric-effect

[image]

I was experimenting with the photoelectric effect to see the effect of frequency of incident light with the current.

Theoretically, the saturation current should be the same irrespective of the frequency used, as it depends only on the intensity of light.

But in my case, the saturation current increased implying stopping potential increased too.

Why does this kind of error occur?

Comment: This isn't an "error" in any usual sense of the word (and definitely not as the error-analysis tag understands the term). You're more likely looking for a word like 'discrepancy'.

Comment: No, the photoelectric yield is not independent of frequency. Not at all. Who gave you that idea?

Comment: Why not read up a bit before doing an experiment http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: Also try the excellent Phet simulation https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/photoelectric

Answer (score 4):

"Theoretically, the saturation current should be the same irrespective of the frequency used, as it depends only on the intensity of light." This is clearly wrong. The reductio ad absurdum case is when the frequency is below the threshold frequency for emission, in which case there is no current at all!

What you *can* safely say is that the saturation current is proportional to the light intensity, *for any given frequency* of light (above the threshold frequency). [Even this won't be true for very high light intensities.]